# Is there a Python2 module that has more accurate Windows OS information than the sys module?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

The following code will generate different values, on the same Windows 10 OS, based on what version of python you are using:

```
import sys
info = sys.getwindowsversion()
major = info.major
```

On a Windows 10 machine, in python2: major == 6  (*which is not the correct value*)

On a Windows 10 machine, in python3: major == 10  (*the correct value*)

I'm in the unfortunate position of needing to use python2 here, but the values it is returning are not accurate.  Is there a module, available in python2, that will give me the accurate values for windows version information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2:

```
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-10-10.0.17134'
```

Python 3:

```
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0'
```

Besides that, unlike `sys.getwindowsversion`, you can also run this on Linux:

```
>>> platform.platform()
'Linux-5.4.0-51-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29'
```

There is also `platform.version()` which gives you just the version without the OS name.